# Why my prototype chain become broken?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'am learnig JavaScript and I need some help to understand what happens in my browser.
I have three JS classes:

```
function A(){}
function B(){}
function C(){}
B.prototype = new A();
C.prototype = new B();
a = new A(); // a instanceof A
b = new B(); // b instanceof A,B
c = new C(); // c instanceof A,B,C
```

But when I call:

```
A.prototype = new C();
// a is not instanceof A
// b is not instanceof A 
// c is not instanceof A
// c is instanceof B
```

Could you please help me to understand what happens when I build such cycle prototype chain and why it breaks existing prototype chain?

Update:
I've found a special method to get prototype of the object, but it makes it not easier to understand.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(a) // A{}
Object.getPrototypeOf(b) // A{}
Object.getPrototypeOf(c) // B{}
```

Comment: That looks like a circular reference. (`A.prot->B; B.prot->C; C.prot->A; A.prot->B; B.prot->C; C.prot->A;` etc, etc, etc) That's not gonna work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular reference, when you add `A.prototype = new C();`:

```
A references B
B references C
C references A
A references B
etc...
```

That's why your code breaks, since that **can** not work, there's no fix for it, that I know of.

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but it's not look like as a circular reference. **`A prototype: C->B->A->A->Object` |
`B prototype: A->A->Object` |
`C prototype: B->A->A->Object`**